# change role of wordpress users when they edit profile

Tags: user-roles

I want a function so that if current user role = tempUser and they change their password in the edit profile section their role will change to subscriber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to add an action to the [`profile_update`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update) hook. That hook passes two parameters: the `$user_id` and `$old_user_data`. We can use those to see if the user is in the tempUser role. If they are, then we compare the old user password to the new user password. If the passwords are different, then we update the user role.

```
//* Add action to hook which fires after a user updates their profile
add_action( 'profile_update', 'wpse_263873_profile_update', 10, 2 );
function wpse_263873_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
  //* Get the user and escape early if they have the tempUser role
  $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
  if( ! in_array( 'tempUser', $user->roles ) ) {
    return;
  }
  //* If the old user_pass isn't exactly equal to the new user_pass
  if( $old_user_data->user_pass !== $user->user_pass ) {
     //* Update the role
     wp_update_user( [
       'ID'   => $user_id, 
       'role' => 'subscriber', 
     ] );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! Also, Im using cimy plugin, do you know if you can change the role of the users if field_name =! "" (is not blank) and then change the role? https://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

Comment: I've never used that plugin, but you can try adding another conditional before you update the user: if( "" !== get_cimyFieldValue( $user_id, $field_name ) ) {}